# How to Gitignore binary files?

Tags: php, git, gitignore

Is it possible to gitigonre binary files by sniffing them? Unfortunatly I have a Zend Encoded PHP files. Git says that they are binary files. But I also have PHP files that are not encoded. Is it possible to gitignore only the binary PHP files?[image: binary PHP file]

Comment: `Is it possible to gitigonre binary files` ... you lost me there already.  Why are you versioning binary files with Git, unless they are fairly small files such as maybe icons?

Comment: I don't want to version binray PHP files. I want to version normal PHP files.

Comment: Git ignores files based on their name, not on their content. Put the names and/or wildcards of file/directory names into `.gitignore` and don't forget to `git rm --cached` the files you want to ignore and are currently tracked by Git.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to gitigonre binary files by sniffing them

Not directly, no.

Git's ignore rules are, like too many things in Git, complicated; but there are two parts that are simple:

- Any *tracked* file is never ignored.  Git defines an *untracked* file as a file that is in the *work-tree* but not in the *index*, so a tracked file is a file that is in the index.  (If it's in the index and not in the work-tree, it's tracked but also deleted.  Of course, this also requires that we define what the *index* and *work-tree* are, but for this answer, I'll just leave them undefined here.)
- For each untracked file, Git can either *complain about it:*

  ```
  Untracked files:
    (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

          foo.ext
  ```

  or, of course, not complain about it; and `git add .` can then either add it, or, of course, not add it.  Note that once added, the file is now *tracked* and ignore entries cannot affect it until it becomes *untracked* again (which you achieve by removing the file from the index—the index's state is not constant and permanent, but it *is* complicated, and removing something that (a) is tracked and (b) has been committed, has consequences).

It's this second item that is controlled by `.gitignore` entries: will Git complain about these files, and will `git add .` add them so that they become tracked?  To find out, Git will read `.gitignore` files (and `.git/info/exclude` and `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`—see [the gitignore documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) for additional details).

The entries in `.gitignore` are lists of file names, file paths, and/or [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) like `*.ext`.  These look only at the *name* of the file, not the content.

You could write a program that writes `.gitignore` files based on file contents, which is what I mean by *not directly* above: you would run your program and it would update any appropriate `.gitignore` files to ignore additional files that are currently untracked-but-not-ignored and are causing complaints.